# Error in syntax of long python function call

Tags: python, lambda, syntax-error, apply

I can't figure out the syntax error here:

```
predicted_df['business_days_rocket'] = predicted_df.apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x['PredictionTargetDateBOM'].date(), x['DayAfterTargetDateEOM'].date(), holidays=[list(k: v for k, v in holidays.US(years=x['PredictionTargetDateBOM'].year).items() if v in my_set)[index] for index in [list(holidays.US(years=x['PredictionTargetDateBOM'].year).values()).index(item)]], axis = 1))# for item in rocket_holiday_including_observed if item in list(holidays.US(years=x['PredictionTargetDateBOM'].year).values())], axis = 1)
                                                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This seems to be a dict comprehension which must be included in curly braces, not round parentheses.

Comment: `k: v for k, v ...` is only valid in a dict comprehension, but you're trying to use it like a generator (inside a `list()` call).

Comment: @jarmod I thought this was stackoverflow not snarkoverflow

Comment: @Julien you're confusing indirect, sarcastic comments with direct, good advice.